# Versioned URLs: how can I tell search engines about more recent versions of the current page?

Tags: url, seo, versioning

I'll explain with a comparison of the hosted documentation for two projects: PostgreSQL and Django. The PostgreSQL project has documentation which follows the schema `http://www.postgresql.org/docs/<MAJOR>.<MINOR>`, while the Django project has documentation which follows the URL schema `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/<MAJOR>.<MINOR>`. Google, however, treats these projects very differently: when searching Google for "Django foobar", the results all link to the most recent version, as is probably desired; but when searching Google for "Postgres foobar", the results link to an ad hoc variety of different versions, some of which are very old.

It seems like the Django project has some technique for informing Google of the most recent documentation. However, I don't know what this technique could be. I would like to know in order to host my own versioned documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django has the [canonical link element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) configured in all versions

```
<link rel="canonical"  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/">
```

And: `/en/stable/topics/http/urls/` redirects to the newest version.

For now that is: `/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/`

So google ends up showing the latest version :)